# In Solr, how to get all the unique values from a field? there are more than 100 values?

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

Below query gives be the unique values of that field. But it returns only top 100. Not sure how to get all the unique values.

"'http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*%3A*&rows=0&facet=on&facet.field=txt'"

*PS: My field is a tokenized field. Not sure if that makes any difference.*

Answer (score 3):

You can use `facet.limit` to change the number of returned values. Set it to `-1` to make Solr return all possible values for a field and not just the top 100.

```
&facet=on&facet.field=txt&facet.limit=-1
```

You can also use `f.txt.facet.limit=-1` if you have more than one facet and just want to change the value for that single field.

You can also [use the Terms component to retrieve the tokens indexed](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/terms-component.html) for a specific field - depending on your use case it might be more efficient to use the terms component instead - you'll have to evaluate the performance for your exact use case and setup.

Comment: Awesome!!!.. thanks. MatsLindh.  Setting facet.limit=-1 did the magic. I will check out the terms component and post an updated soon.